# how to make two jersey components listen to the same annotation?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a jersey application, which does add a `@Provider` to some annotation `@MyAnnotation`.  The `@Provider` class is `MyAnnotationListener implements ApplicationEventListener`.

How can i add multiple `MyAnnotationListener` instances to jersey, so that every `@MyAnnotation`-annotated method does trigger all those registered instances? The problem i see here is, that the MyAnnotationListener-instances need some internal reference, and therefore cannot be instantiated using a parameter-free constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that you want to treat the annotation like a [name binding annotation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9916). AFAIK, this only works for filter and interceptors

The only way I can think is just to get the [`ExtendedUriInfo`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html) from the `RequestEvent` in the `onEvent` method of the `RequestEventListener`, then do some reflection to get the annotation. Check if it's null.

For example

```
@Provider
public class TestApplicationListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Target({METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface SomeAnnotation {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent ae) {}

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent re) {
        return new RequestListener();
    }

    public static class RequestListener implements RequestEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(RequestEvent re) {

            switch (re.getType()) {
                case RESOURCE_METHOD_START:
                    if (hasAnnotation(re)) 
                        System.out.println("-- record method start event --");
                    break;
                case RESOURCE_METHOD_FINISHED:
                    if (hasAnnotation(re))
                        System.out.println("-- record method end event --");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private boolean hasAnnotation(RequestEvent e) {
            ResourceMethod resourceMethod = e.getUriInfo().getMatchedResourceMethod();
            Invocable invocable = resourceMethod.getInvocable();
            SomeAnnotation annotation = invocable.getHandlingMethod()
                    .getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
            return annotation != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to check the [`RequestEvent.Type`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEvent.Type.html), as the `ResourceMethod` won't be available for all event types.